# What is a good format for Sprint retrospectives?

Tags: scrum, sprint, retrospective

We are doing Sprint retrospectives with the entire team including the ScrumMaster and the Product Owner present. We have constructive discussion and good ideas are being generated. However, to improve implementation we are looking into the start-stop-continue format - what should we start, stop or continue doing from the current process.  What is a good format for Sprint retrospectives?

Comment: We want to capture the specific action that is agreed by the team consensus and improve implementation.

Comment: "Better" is too subjective, and likely to lead to opinion polling. Please consider revising your question to ask something more concrete, to avoid having this question closed as "Not Constructive."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we are using meetingwords.com as a tool for our retro (everyone would put his/her comments there, if you like one of the comments - vote it up (put a star in front of it); here are the topics:

- Was this past sprint successful in your opinion?
- Do you feel that your productivity has increased or decreased?
- What do you need to be more successful in the upcoming sprint?
- What did not work in the previous sprint?
- What’s one thing you would personally do differently in the next sprint?
- What would we as a team need in order to be more efficient and effective to achieve our sprint goals?
- What should we start doing?

At the end we are trying to put together an actionable plan to implement results of the retro meetings.

- Goal (what do we want to achieve and why?)
- Criteria (how would we know if a certain goal has been reached?)
- Milestones (to prevent things from dragging on forever)
- Who is responsible for the implementation

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend some good book resources for retrospective ideas:

- [Agile Retrospective: Making Good Teams Great](http://isbn.nu/0977616649)
- [Gamestorming: A Playbook for Innovators, Rulebreakers, and Changemakers](http://isbn.nu/0596804172)

Answer (score 0):

What I've seen working is something where you take 1-2 learnings from the retrospectives, assign a pass and fail condition, assign an owner and track this as part of the next sprint's retrospective.